# does iCloud support sub-directories?

Tags: ios, icloud, subdirectory

We want to backup a few of our apps' subdirectories (and the files under them) to iCloud and also able to browse those files at runtime, don't find any API/properties for that purpose, is it still possible ?how can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSFileManager`. You create folders in iCloud just like you do in any folder within the app sandbox.

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL *rootURL = [fm URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
NSURL *newFolder = [NSURL URLWithString:@"someFolder" relativeToURL:rootURL];
[fm createDirectoryAtURL:newFolder withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
```

TODO - add proper result and error checking.

Comment: awesome, what about iterate through and traverse the subdirectories?

Comment: Sure. All of the `NSFileManager` methods work. The local iCloud area is just another directory on the filesystem. Other than dealing with concurrency issues, working with the iCloud container is no different than working with the app's sandbox.

Comment: Keep in mind that while you can use `NSFileManager` to traverse and iterate the subdirectories, there are better ways since files can come and go as the user uses the app on multiple devices. The iCloud docs talks about better ways to query for files and listen for changes.